# Flex BlazeDS detect browser close

Tags: spring, apache-flex, browser, blazeds

I have a Flex application that connects to a BlazeDS server using the StreamingAMF channel. I want to detect on the server side in case the browser is closed. I have added an implementation for FlexClientListener & registered it to the FlexClient (FlexContext.getFlexClient().addClientDestroyedListener)

But the clientDestroyed method of Listener is not invoked on browser close. It gets invoked on Session timeout. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to detect browser interactions on a client from the server.

Your best guess is to make use of [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).  It allows your Flash app to communicate with JavaScript, and vice versa.

Use the [JavaScript onClose event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onclose) to trigger some JavaScript which will call a function in your Flash App which will make a remote call to let your server side know that the browser is being closed.

Answer (score 0):

We too had similar issue, not closing the session was causing memory leak in BlazeDS, We wrote the below script in swf wrapper javascript, to make ensure that closing browser invokes session closure code in flex

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function cleanup()
    {
        getMyApplication("swf_filename_without_extension").cleanUp();    
        alert("Disconnected! Press OK to continue.");
    }

    function getMyApplication(appName)
    {
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf ("Microsoft") != -1)
         {
              return window[appName];
         }
         else
         {
              return document[appName];
         }
    }
</script>


<body onbeforeunload="cleanup()">
```

In Flex add a call back on creation complete listener

```
  ExternalInterface.addCallback("cleanUp",cleanUp);
```

and write all your session closure code in cleanUp method.

Note: don't forget to put the alert message in javascript. That will give enough time for cleanUp method to execute.